# Square API with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010, square-connect

```
Dim myUri = New Uri("https://squareup.com/v2/locations")

Dim RQ As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(myUri), HttpWebRequest)

RQ.PreAuthenticate = True    
RQ.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" & Token) '''Token is a Shared string assigned to my current Access Token
RQ.Method = "GET"
RQ.Accept = "application/json"
RQ.ContentType = "application/json"


Using response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(RQ.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) '''''"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
```

Very new to the Square-Connect API and there are no vb.net examples so this was as far as i can get. Im not able to get pass the last line. I always get a 404 error no matter what i try. Anyone know why.

If I use this command (replacing Token with my access Token), in a terminal then I get the result I want in vb.net.

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer Token" https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations

Answer (score 0):

The guys at square quickly found my problem so here is the working code:

```
 Dim myUri = New Uri("https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations")
    Dim RQ As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(myUri), HttpWebRequest)

    RQ.PreAuthenticate = True
    RQ.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token) 'Token is a Shared string assigned to my current Access Token
    RQ.Method = "GET"
    RQ.Accept = "application/json"
    RQ.ContentType = "application/json"


    Using response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(RQ.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```